# Give priority to specific row while fetching via select

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with following data

### Code Dest

atp           ananthapur
blr           bangalore
chn           chennai
del           delhi
hmp           himachal

hyd           hyderbad
goa           goa

I need a query to fetch data such that the rows for codes 'hyd' and 'blr' would remain on top always, and then rest of the rows will follow.

I have done this as below -

```
select code,dest from   (
        select 1 rown,a.* from LOCATION a 
        where a.code in ('hyd','blr')  
        union  
        select 2 rown,b.* from LOCATION b
        where b.code not in ('hyd','blr')
)  
order by rown
```

I can think of doing it in some other ways also. But my question is -

Is there any oracle defined feature to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Oracle has such a feature, it's the `ORDER BY expressions-list` clause.
Try:

```
SELECT * FROM LOCATION a
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN a.code in ('hyd','blr') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```